# Переход по сайту без перезагрузки некоторых элементов

Tags: php, javascript

Как можно реализовать и можно ли, переход по сайту  без перезагрузки некоторых элементов (например меню с верху). То есть есть меню на rr.cam и всякая информация, я перешел по ссылке  на rr.cam/info и меню быстро загрузилось.

Comment: уточните вопрос.

Comment: меню или текст?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь ajax'ом.

Общая схема такая:

При нажатии на ссылку, вы вместо перехода на новый адрес, формируете ajax запрос к серверу для получение информации, и результат складываете в нужный вам элемент страницы.

с помощью jqeury это можно реализовать например так:

```
$('a').click(function(event){ 
$.ajax({url:$(this).attr('href')}).success(
  function(data){
    $('div#updated_element').html(data);
});
//Запрещаем стандартную реакцию на ссылку
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Почитайте документацию jquery по методам ajax, html.

Без использования jquery тоже можно, но более сложно описывать, но принцип тот же.

Для того чтобы было возможно "ходить" назад и менять адрес в строке браузера, можно воспользоватся объектом history. Он правда HTML5, но многие браузеры его поддерживают.

Хорошая статья на хабре есть: http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/

С неё можно начать гуглить.

Comment: Ну, а ссылку в адресной строке как менять?

Comment: Да, секунду, забыл.

Comment: `history.pushState()`